# Can I safely use a straight (Type 1) metal cutoff wheel in angle grinder?

Tags: safety, powertools, cutting, angle-grinder

I have a [Ridgid angle grinder](https://www.homedepot.com/p/RIDGID-18-Volt-OCTANE-Cordless-Brushless-4-1-2-in-Angle-Grinder-Tool-Only-R86042B/306925920) and a [metal cutoff wheel](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Diablo-4-5-in-Diamond-Wheel-for-Metal-Cutting-DDD045DIA101F/301454106?MERCH=REC-_-pipsem-_-202830999-_-301454106-_-N).

On page 7 of the [manual](https://images.homedepot-static.com/catalog/pdfImages/ec/ec0c9a74-e26a-47a6-97ee-73fbe5571e70.pdf) it states:

> Use ONLY Type 27 depressed center grinding wheels (such as the one provided  with this product). NEVER attach a Type 1 straight or cut-off wheel to this angle grinder. Use for any other purpose is not recommended and creates a hazard, which will result in serious injury.

[image]

After reading some online forums, asking some contractor friends, and watching YouTube videos it seems that everyone simply uses a Type 1 wheel to cut metal and move on with their life.

PS: *I won't acknowledge the countless people that use an angle grinder without the guard. I will absolutely be putting the guard in the correct position.*

As far as I can tell I just have to reverse the clamp nut and it securely holds the Type 1 cutoff wheel in place.

Am I using the wrong tool or wrong cutoff wheel or are there simply so many more Type 1 wheel accidents that companies just try to distance themselves from Type 1?

Even the cutoff wheel packaging says "for use with angle grinders" and has a picture of an angle grinder.

**Important**: I am trying to solicit authoritative answers which can properly explain why one should not use a Type 1 disc. I do not wish for polling answers such as "I've done it so you're fine".

Comment: I looked at a popular corded angle grinder from Makita and the [manual](https://cdn.makitatools.com/apps/cms/doc/prod/GA4/0052722d-16d9-4980-80c1-88b9945740fe_GA4530_IM.pdf) doesn't have the same warning.

Comment: @JPhi1618 I can't find it right now but one forum mentioned that Dewalt makes an angle grinder for which you can special order parts to convert it to accept Type 1 discs.

Comment: If you look at [this manual](https://cdn.makitatools.com/apps/cms/doc/prod/XAG/b3512e6a-eeae-4d5a-b288-9e0da4a99de8_XAG16,17_IM_885615-949.pdf) for a cordless Makita grinder, it looks like there is a special operation you need to do with the guard when switching to a depressed center disk.  I didn't totally understand what was going on, but maybe the Rigid lacks that kind of flexibility.  Is there a Home Depot  nearby that you could go to and look at the grinder?  They sell loose cut off wheels, so you should be able to try and fit a type 1 and type 27 to the tool and see what happens.

Comment: @JPhi1618 I have both the tool and cutoff wheel in my possession. Are you referring to page 21, part #13 of the Makita manual?

Comment: I was talking about the ~page 10 area, but yea, I see the extra "shrouded" guard on page 21.  Full disclosure - I don't know why it says you cant - I'm as curious as you are. If you look at some YouTube reviews of the tool, people sure do use it with a flat cut off disk.  I'm sure no one read the manual...

Comment: I would always suggest that you follow the manufacturer suggestion. I don't always do so myself, but I recommend it to others. My best suggestion is to maybe get an angle grinder that does allow cutting wheels.

Comment: @JPhi1618 Based on the comments here and stuff I've read elsewhere I think that this all boils down to two things. 1) Can the disc be securely fastened to the tool and not wobble. 2) A full wheel guard is recommended for Type 1 wheels; presumably the discs shatter more violently and are prone to flying laterally from the tool.

Comment: @JPhi1618 Though I would like to find some authoritative explanation of this :-/

Comment: @JIMMYPlay I'm already invested in the Ridgid line of battery tools so I was hoping to stick with Ridgid. I know I can look for tools which explicitly support cutting wheels but I think that the overarching question of "Can I safely use a metal cutoff wheel in angle grinder?" is useful regardless of the tool brand.

Answer (score 5):

I think I have enough research to make an answer to this.  I believe it comes down to the guard available for this tool and it not meeting the requirements for a "Type 1" cut off disk.

[This Ridgid forum](https://www.ridgidforum.com/forum/power-tools/power-tool-discussion-forum/33876-cut-off-discs-with-angle-grinder) has what is supposed to be a quote from Ridgid:

> The RIDGID R1001 Angle Grinder has an included type 27 guard and is certified to Underwriters Laboratories (U.L.) product safety standards. U.L. requires only type 27 depressed center grinding wheels be used with type 27 guards. Type 1 straight or cut-off wheels have no depressed center posing a safety concern to the operator when connected to a type 27 guard. In no circumstance should a type 1 straight cut-off wheel be used with a type 27 guard. Please contact RIDGID customer for further assistance: 866-539-1710.

This is for a different model, but it does show that they do limit the wheels on their tools based on the guards.

I also found [this PDF](https://abrasivessafety.com/Portals/0/Documents/safety-recommendations-bonded-abrasives-fepa-abrasivessafety.pdf) from an abrasives saftey site that shows an enclosed guard is used for cutoff wheels:

[image: Angle grinder guard types]

I also found a [Makita manual](https://cdn.makitatools.com/apps/cms/doc/prod/XAG/b3512e6a-eeae-4d5a-b288-9e0da4a99de8_XAG16,17_IM_885615-949.pdf) that shows an optional enclosed guard for cut off wheels (#13):

[image: Makita diagram]

And here is that product [sold seperately](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B005YSA6PC):

[image: cut off guard]

So, all of that points to the guard being the "breaking point" for the type 1 disc support.  This is probably because the company had some legal issue in the past so they have decided to officially not support that type of disk with their tools while other brands are happy to sell different guards (speculation alert).

I guess what it comes down to is trusting the included guard to contain the explosion of a cracked type 1 disc.

Comment: Thank you for this. I think that we've hit the nail on the head. I Googled "type 1 cut off wheel guard" and came across https://www.nortonabrasives.com/en-us/resources/expertise/what-you-should-know-about-grinding-wheel-guards which seems to give a nice explanation to back up your research

Comment: There could be additional reasons to not use the disk, but this seems like the most talked about.

Comment: Now to figure out why the open-sided guard is unsuitable for use if neither you nor another person is exposed to that side. I'm going to give Ridgid a call later today and see what they have to say about this topic; hopefully it's not some scripted legalese.

Comment: Type 1 cutoff wheels are too close when mounted in a type 27 guard, the wheel can flex into the guard while cutting causing an accident. Type 27 cutoff wheels are common, and offset just like the grinding wheels for safe distance from the guard.

Comment: @MatthewGauthier Thanks for the input - I was at a home improvement store last night and I did see the offset cutoff wheels.  I never knew they existed and had never looked for them because I always reach right for the flat discs.

Comment: @MatthewGauthier How would you interpret "NEVER attach a Type 1 straight or cut-off wheel to this angle grinder."? Home Depot also carries type 27 cut-off wheels.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus You should always use the type 27 cutoff wheel. Type 1 wheels are for cutoff tools and may impact the guard on your grinder. Some brands of grinder (like the Makita in this answer) offer an enclosed guard as an option which allows you to use straight wheels.

Comment: @MatthewGauthier Interesting, I read it as "NEVER attach a Type 1 straight or cut-off wheel *regardless of type* to this angle grinder."

Comment: I think I read it as "Type 1 straight" or "cut off wheel", like that was two names for the same thing.

Comment: @JPhi1618 Interesting, you would think they would have wrote "NEVER attach a Type 1 straight (cut-off) wheel to this angle grinder." instead.

Comment: @JPhi1618 I called Ridgid yesterday and the guy basically said "Yeah, don't use those if it tells you not to in the manual, it will void your warranty." So much for that avenue of information...

Comment: Can anyone provide some models that are specifically specified to handle type 1 cutting?

Comment: @BrianG, there is [this Ryobi model](https://www.homedepot.com/p/RYOBI-18-Volt-ONE-Cordless-Brushless-4-1-2-in-Cut-Off-Tool-Angle-Grinder-Tool-Only-P423/301853890) that claims to come with a type 1 and type 27 guard.  That's what you are looking for.  I'm not sure anyone makes a "type 1" specific tool. They are all just regular angle grinders that happen to also have an available Type 1 guard.  I've found that most type 1 guards are an optional accessory (that no one buys or uses unless OSHA or similar mandates it).

Comment: @JPhi1618 I was just looking at that specific grinder. I notice it is listed as a grinder / cut off tool. In reality it probably is a standard grinder with the extra type 1 guard. I think it is sufficient to satisfy my paranoia, though. Luckily I already have the ryobi battery setup. It seems like a cut off specific tool usually utilizes a 6inch disk and is in the ballpark of $250. This ryobi tool looks like the optimal solution. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can, and I have done so to cut hundreds of masonry pavers. **The problem is that the nut cannot be adequately tightened to ensure safety, and you'll flex the blade, potentially damaging it and causing injury.** If you can avoid those issues with solid backing and positive centering there's no reason you can't use flat blades.

One solution would be to install a washer (or stack of them) to fill the recessed cavity behind the blade, then tighten the nut. If it's a high-quality steel blade, and not fiber, this probably isn't necessary. As I mentioned, I wore through several diamond masonry blades in my 7" grinder with no issues.

Comment: Thank you for this answer but the solution seems to introduce hackiness which I am not comfortable doing to a 10k rpm wheel of death. Take note of page 34 in the manual I linked. If I place the disc onto the disc flange (J) and reverse the clamp nut (B) then the disc rests flush against the large outer surface of J and B.

Comment: The manual doesn't have that many pages, but the outcome is the same anyway assuming that you have solid metal and positive centering. FYI, "[flush](https://www.carpentry-tips-and-tricks.com/Carpentry-Terms.html#F)" is not a synonym for "tight to".

Comment: I think flush was the wrong word. The disc lays flat on part J, the inner circle of J goes through the center of the disc and is the same thickness as the disc, and part B threads flat and tight onto the disc. I am unable to wobble the disc with my hand and it looks perfectly straight when running at max rpm.

Answer (score 2):

Just found that the Milwaukee 43-54-1090 guard is the exact fit for (at least 18v R86041) 4.5" Ridgid angle grinders. The 43-54-0920 is similar, but the hole is smaller and the cutouts are only on top.

They run about $15-$20 + shipping/taxes. Flange nut provided works for depressed and non depressed disks. Reverse and mount. The flange nut design has a recessed center on the flat side to act as the seal for thin blades (like my Type 1 .045 thick cut off discs) as it can securely clamp them in without any other movement.

1090 on left, OEM Ridgid on right.
[image: 1090 on left, OEM Ridgid on right.]

1090 on top with top+bottom cutouts, 0920 on bottom with bottom cutouts only and smaller diameter hole.
[image: 1090 on top with top+bottom cutouts, 0920 on bottom with bottom cutouts only and smaller diameter hole.]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. This sounds like an extended reply to one of the other answers, rather than an answer itself; would you edit it to be a stan-alone answer? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.

Comment: The answer is because you can use a type 1 cutting disc without a proper guard, but this is a proper guard that fits more recent Ridgid grinders. It is an available item that gives proper coverage against disc blowouts and the flange that is provided with Ridgid grinders properly seats type 1 discs.

Comment: Thanks; you should edit this into your answer.

Answer (score 1):

A flat cut off will work but the user is at serious risk of injury... because IF, for ANY REASON the medium you are working on causes that thin, brittle disc to break apart while spinning at high R.P.M., it is now shrapnel. Better hope your guard is between the tool and your face- OUCH! (I have seen E.R. pictures where chunks even penetrated full face shields). IF a decent size piece hits a finger you will probably loose it. Dont believe me? google it OR dig out your dremel grab a disc see how easily it breaks it to dust in your fingers. Yes, it's much smaller and the larger ones are usually reinforced but it's still the same concept. Yes, it will work but straight wheels are not designed for lateral stress and IF it fails, your screwed